# Html css needs to be changed to look like the image posted (Implemented in dotnet core application)

Tags: html, css, .net

The submenus are displayed as shown in the capture1 based on the html and css where chevrons are not aligned.But it should be aligned as per the capture2.

**Capture 1:**

[image]

**Capture 2:**

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="submenu" class="submenu-manure-wizard" style="background-color:#f2f2f2">
    <ul class="submenu-manure-wrapper submenu-manure-wizard-list clearfix">
        @foreach (var item in Model.subMenuOptions)
        {
            if (@item.MainMenuId == 2)
            {
                <li id="@item.Controller@item.Action@item.Id" class="submenu-manure-wizard-item" style="display:none">
                    <a id="eMenu" href='@Url.Action(@item.Action, @item.Controller)'>
                        <span class="wizard-name" style="vertical-align: text-top">@item.Name</span>

                        <div style="width: 30px;height:19px;display:block">
                            <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 199" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 199;" xml:space="preserve"><style type="text/css">
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                .st0 {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    fill: none;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    stroke: #000000;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    stroke-width: 11;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    stroke-miterlimit: 5;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                }
</style><polyline class="st0" points="33.5,-0.5 136,102 36.5,201.5 " /></svg>
                        </div>

                    </a>

                </li>

            }
        }
    </ul>

    <ul class="submenu-fields-wrapper submenu-manure-wizard-list clearfix">
        @foreach (var item in Model.subMenuOptions)
        {
            if (@item.MainMenuId == 3)
            {
                <li id="@item.Controller@item.Action@item.Id" class="submenu-fields-wizard-item" style="display:none">
                    <a id="eMenu" href='@Url.Action(@item.Action, @item.Controller)'>
                        <span class="wizard-name" style="vertical-align: text-top">@item.Name</span>
                        @if (!(@item.Id == 5))
                        {
                            <div class="wizard-item" style="width: 30px;height:19px;display:block">
                                <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 199" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 199;" xml:space="preserve"><style type="text/css">
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    .st0 {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        fill: none;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        stroke: #000000;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        stroke-width: 11;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        stroke-miterlimit: 5;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    }
</style><polyline class="st0" points="33.5,-0.5 136,102 36.5,201.5 "/></svg>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wizardsubmenu {
    padding: 0px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b0cee2;
}

#submenu-manure-width {
    width: 20%;
}

.submenu-manure-wrapper {
    max-width: 1210px;
    max-height: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 150px;
    padding-left: 150px;
}

.submenu-fields-wrapper {
    max-width: 930px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.submenu-manure-wizard {
    /*padding: 5px 0;*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b0cee2;
}

.submenu-manure-wizard-list {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.submenu-manure-wizard-item {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
}

.submenu-fields-wizard-item {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Attached the image ...where submenu items need to be highlighted.SVG images need to aligned to the submenu items.

I have main menu and submenu.The captures show the submenu.Submenus are being loaded from the output of the mainmenu.Am using svg images after the submenu items which is causing the svg pages to float as shown in the image.I have attached the css and html pages i have used .

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: I have got a main level menus and sub level menus that are loaded based on the main menu.I have to load submenus as shown in the capture 2 using a chevron svg at the end of each submenu which is not turning out to be good.Am looking for a html and css that loads the submenus.I provided the css and html files that i have used for generating the way i did.Am looking for modifications on that.